# How do I use an optional extension in a .gitignore file?

Tags: git

I have the following two files

```
./file
./file.text
./file.yo
```

Now I want to exclude all of these from git and I am not sure how. Thinking like regex I would do this `**/file(?:\..*)`, but I cannot translate this to the gitignore. I see there is an optional char which based on documentation appears to be `!`. But the documentation does not provide examples and I am not sure this is correct.

How would I write a `.gitignore` line for excluding all these files at once?

Comment: They are fileglobs. Have you checked https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore `./file.*`

Comment: is the `.` like the regex `.` is it saying any char?

Comment: And how does that make it optional?

Comment: Why are there 3 files when you mentioned 2? 
Are those the exact file names? ('/' is not allowed in file name?)
I presume the file name is just 'file.*'?

Comment: `.` is dot — gitignore file-matching is globs like on the commandline

Comment: Right so if I did what you suggested the first file would not be included correct?

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to remove "file" and only match against those two extensions (not "file.blah")? And you only want it to apply to "file" and not any other filenames (not "blah.yo")?

Comment: No I want to match all 3 with 1 line

Comment: So similar to 

    `file
    file.*` but only on one line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match all 3 files with 1 line, use `file*`, which basically matches any files beginning with 'file'.

If the files are in a specific directory, you can also use `<directory>/file*` to reduce the match scope.